# relative clause with a preposition

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses

> The insight the experience offered about life, the world, and her place in it.

Without the PP Phrase, the sentence is understandable to me . But with the PP phrase being included, it's kind of confusing.

Does the sentence mean :
The insight is offered by the experience, and the insight is about life , the world, and her place in it.

---

The above sentence is excerpted from the sentence below.

> You’ll recall that Dr. Jill divided her 
>   popular TED talk, “My Stroke of Insight,” into three sections that lasted 
>   six minutes each: the circuitry of the brain, the day of the stroke, and **the 
>   insight the experience offered about life, the world, and her place in it**.

Comment: It's confusing me too. It doesn't seem to be a complete sentence. Something seems to have been left out.

Comment: @DonB. Yes, i only excerpted part of it as the sentence is quite long, i've added the whole sentence to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *You’ll recall that Dr. Jill divided her popular TED talk, “My Stroke*
>   *of Insight,” into three sections that lasted six minutes each: the*
>   *circuitry of the brain, the day of the stroke, and **the insight (that) the***
>   ***experience offered about life, the world, and her place in it.***

The bit in bold (a noun phrase, not a sentence) can be paraphrased as *the experience offered insight about life, the world, and her place in the world*

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I provided this answer before extra information was added to the question to clarify it. With the additional information, this answer is now incorrect. However, I'm going to leave it as is rather than just delete it—it was an accurate answer to the question that was asked at the time I provided it.

---

That is not an complete sentence. There is a subject, but no verb.

It's no different than saying:

> ✘ The truck (that was large).

(What *about* the truck?)

In this case, it's saying:

> ✘ The insight (*the experience offered about life, the universe, and her place in it*).

The sentence is unfinished. What *about* the insight?

As it stands, it doesn't *mean* anything . . .

Comment: Thanks, the original sentence is really long, so I only excerpt part of it. This is the whole sentence :You’ll recall that Dr. Jill divided her 
popular TED talk, “My Stroke of Insight,” into three sections that lasted 
six minutes each: the circuitry of the brain, the day of the stroke, and **the 
insight the experience offered about life, the world, and her place in it.**

Answer (score 0):

The last phrase of the sentence refers to someone named Dr. Jill. It seems that she suffered a stroke, and she made a talk or lecture about what happened when she had the stroke and what she learned from it. I interpret the last phrase of the sentence, which you were asking about, to mean that  the experience of having the stroke gave her greater knowledge of what it means for her to be alive. But it's hard to know for sure what that means without hearing the talk.